# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE skips html tags inside <>

Tags: html, mysql

I have a file like this

myfile.tpl

```
{if !$smarty.action}
    <div id="bar">
{/if}
....
```

I am using this command for loading file into mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (col text);
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.tpl'  INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```

when i use `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1`
the result is:

```
{if !$smarty.action} {/if}
```

and it simply skips `<div id="bar">` in output.

Comment: When you view it in a browser?  Try view source.

Comment: basically your seeing the interpreted html, so tags are not visible

Comment: @AbraCadaver It's not browser problem... i just open mytable with SELECT statement

Comment: Are you sure that <div ... is skipping. I just tried and it works fine.

Comment: @Rahul...sure, it skips all html tags inside <>

Comment: No, it works fine. even the <div part as well comes. if you want I can put it as answer showing the steps.

Comment: @Rahul, strange!...but it does not work for me...is it related to mysql version? mine is 5.1.7

Comment: @Rahul, i checked with mysql 5.5 and same problem. please put your answer. i like to view it

Answer (score 0):

Followed the same steps as yours:

`myfile.tpl` has below contents

```
{if !$smarty.action}
    <div id="bar">
{/if}
```

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (col text);
```

Loading the data

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\SO_Test\\myfile.tpl'  INTO TABLE mytable 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```

Viewing the data returns

```
select * from mytable
```

[image]

MySQL Version running

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"

'innodb_version', '5.6.17'
'version', '5.6.17'
```

Comment: Perhaps it is because of mysql version!
Moreover, there is tabs before `<div id="bar">`

Comment: @Amir, may be. suggest you to try the same in version 5.6.17 and get it confirmed once. don't forget to accept the answer if it a help at all.